# ASP change URL inside of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

on my ASPX webpage I have this code:

```
<tr action="_forms/properties/properties.aspx?id=FILLID&amp;objTypeCode=5', 'tmp', 420, 505)" id="mnu_properties">--%>
   <td style="border: 1px solid #dcdfe5;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;" nowrap colspan="2">Vlastnosti</td>
 </tr>
```

I need to fill somehow the parametr FILLID, when page is loaded, or during update of the webpage.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: what is the source for `FILLID` in your page ?

Comment: The source could be in parametr of URL, but also could be changed during work with the page.

Comment: tr-element does not have action-attribute, I recommend using [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for this instead

Comment: In my case it is working, as it is menu table

Comment: Your implementation might work but that's a different story than valid html. That html is not valid, by changing that to data-action and using that attribute you can make the html valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a fuction server side and embed the call in design view:

```
<tr action="_forms/properties/properties.aspx?id=<%= GetValue%>&amp;objTypeCode=5', 'tmp', 420, 505)" id="mnu_properties">
   <td style="border: 1px solid #dcdfe5;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;" nowrap colspan="2">Vlastnosti</td>
 </tr>
```

And server side code (vb.net example):

```
Protected Function GetValue() As String
    Return "My Value"
End Function
```